# Can we invoke async() inside a thread?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++17

May be a stupid question , google didnt help me . Is it a good practice to invoke a asycn() inside a thread.
Here is my scenario .

```
Thread1()
{
   auto fu = async(checkStatus);
   while ( waitEvent && fu.get() )
   {
     ..
     fu = async(checkStatus);
   }
    
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: So your title is really, "Should we..." not "Can we..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `std::async` can be called within a thread.

It can be a good idea, and it can be a bad idea.

Generally you want threads to be doing things, and not waiting on stuff, as much as possible.  Ideally you should be treating threads as primitive types, and solve your problems *on top of* structures built on `std::thread` or `std::jthread`, not directly using them.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we invoke async() inside a thread?

Yes. In fact, everything you do in a program is inside  a thread unless the program runs on a single-process system (i.e. some embedded system).